# How to get values between two date time in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#

I would like to get values between two Datetime which values between one day ago and today but I don't know how I do it.

```
_db.Contact.Where(p => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) < p.Date <= DateTime.Now && p.Email == entity.Email).ToList()
```

Comment: You're very close. You can think of this as having 3 conditions. Date greater than or equal to a day ago, Date less than today, and  matching email. All three have to be true, so you need to use the && operator between all 3 conditions. You currently only have it between two of the conditions.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you so. I added your advice to my code. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but you can't chain conditions like that in C#. You need to make two separate conditions for the `<` and the `<=`:

```
_db.Contact.Where(p => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) <  p.Date 
    && p.Date <= DateTime.Now 
    && p.Email == entity.Email)
.ToList()
```